# Docker - only image with operating system?

Tags: docker

So far I have only seen images with some operating system as a base layer. Is this necessary ?  Is it possible to run some container without an operating system ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is `FROM scratch` which you'll find if you follow how the images on docker hub have been built (you may have to follow various `FROM x` lines to different images until you reach scratch). Scratch is empty, completely empty, no libraries, no shells, no files at all. It's designed as a starting point that you can copy a bunch of files into.

You can also use scratch if you have a statically linked binary and don't want anything else inside the container. However note that debugging the container becomes more difficult since you can't launch a shell inside the container, but that also means attackers can't do that either.

Comment: Ok, so first layer is empty - when we download ubuntu it downloads libararies, ls, cp, ... Yeah ?

Comment: When you use ubuntu as your base image you get `ls`, `cp`, `apt-get`, shells, etc, yes.

Answer (score 1):

An operating system consist of the kernel and userland utilities.  So, there are no Docker images with "operating systems" as base layer, but a lot of images named after operating system distributions with their particular userland utilities.

You can create a Docker image from a tarball with anything you like.  But it wouldn't be useful if it lacks /bin/sh and you want to include a RUN in the Dockerfile.